# How to extract list element names in lapply to rename files

Tags: r

I want to simply print out the names of the list elements I have so that I can use them to create new filenames to print out a dataset

Here is what I have but basically it doesn't give me a result and tells me it couldn't find the function 'name'.

```
ReportOp<-function(x){
theNamedFile<-paste(name(x),"~\\Myfile.pdf")
}

lapply(mylist,ReportOp)
```

Comment: If it is the names of the `list`, then `ReportOp(mylist)`  BTW, you need `names(x)` and not `name(x)`  Also, the function name is `ReportOp` and not `ReportPDF`

Comment: That will give me all the names, but how do I paste each named element?

Comment: show what is `mylist`,

Comment: Are you talking about the `list` names like `l1 <- list(a=1, b = 2, c= 3); names(l1)`?

Comment: `paste` is vectorized. Just try it: `paste(names(mylist),"foo")`.

Comment: Yes I would like to paste the name of each element of the list to the ~\\Myfile.pdf

Comment: Please check my first comment.  You have `name` instead of `names`

Comment: Aha. Yes thank you it was name instead of names. Please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `names` instead of `name` in the OP's function, use `paste0` instead of `paste` if we don't need a whitespace between the `names` and the new string,  and return 'theNamedFile', then apply the function directly on the 'mylist'

```
ReportOp<-function(x){
    theNamedFile <- paste0(names(x),"~\\Myfile.pdf")
    theNamedFile
 }
ReportOp(mylist)
```

---

If we apply it using `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist, ReportOp)
```

this will return the `names` of the elements (if is a named vector or the column names of `data.frame`) as a `list`

Comment: that pastes the subelements of the list to ~\\Myfile.pdf rather than the names of each element in the list

Comment: @SebastianZeki  I showed two options as I am not completely sure which one you wanted

Comment: does this still apply for a list of dataframes? How can I get the dataframe names contained within a list- or should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Yes, it will work on a `list` of data.frames (the second one)